# The sound of any video, from youtube or from any media player, stops randomly after seconds or minutes

Tags: windows-7, audio, video, flash

The sound of any video from YouTube or from any media player stops randomly after seconds or minutes.

I searched the Internet and saw similar problem blaming Flash Player for the problem.
I tried installing an older version of Flash Player or no Flash Player at all and still the sound stops randomly when playing videos using any media player.

The sound works fine when I use headphones.

My system is Windows 7 32-bit. The automatic update was turned on when I set up Windows.
My laptop is Toshiba Satellite L755

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which browser is this in? (Or all?)

Comment: All browsers
I tried firefox and Google chrome

Comment: I installed first the newest version of flash player

Comment: To be clear, the sound stops by the video continues playing on glitch-free?

Comment: yes, the video continue playing in both youtube videos on the browsers or videos played by any media player

Comment: "The sound works fine when I use headphones.". Hmm, is your [audio driver up to date](http://support.toshiba.com/support/family?fname=Satellite)?

Comment: yes, i updated the driver now 
it last little longer but stops also later :D
it is the first time to face such problem